# Updating SQLite + Entity Framework Core tables in WPF application

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have a .NET Core 7 WPF application, and I am using SQLite.

In entry I run this code:

```
// Database
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SpproContext>()
                             .UseSqlite(DB_CONNECTION);
var context = new SpproContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
context.Database.EnsureCreated();

serviceCollection.AddDbContextPool<SpproContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(DB_CONNECTION));
```

As the app is in (perpetual) development, the model changes. When I add a new table, SQLite throws an error

> Table is not created

I can fix it by doing

```
context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
```

and deleting my database, so it is recreated. However this is not a good solution, I do not want all the clients using my app to lose all their data every time I make an update.

Is there a way to check to see if the database matches, and if it doesn't run an update?

Similar to how you would `add-migration`, `update-database` with Entity Framework Core.

Comment: For sure you can solve this problem, but in my humble opinion this is a wrong approach to an X/Y problem that begins with a not so correct implementation of an architecture.

Comment: Can you explain more so I can investigate another solution? Should I not be using sqlite in wpf?

Comment: read the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=vs#apply-migrations-at-runtime